# How can I associate a schema with a json file using lsp-mode/lsp-json

Tags: lsp-mode, lsp

If you read the documentation for lsp-mode-lsp-json [here](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-json/#lsp-json-schemas), this is the section that deals with setting schemas:

> Available configurations
>
> lsp-json-schemas
>
> Default: nil
>
> Associate schemas to JSON files in the current project

I have no idea how to use that. Is there an example somewhere?

> lsp-json-schemas is a variable defined in ‘lsp-json.el’.
>
> Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>
> Associate schemas to JSON files in the current project
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in version 6.3 of the lsp-mode package.

I googled, but can't find an example of how to use this variable anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know how to use the `lsp-json-schemas` variable, but with this mode properly activated in emacs you can add a top-level `$schema` property to the object you are presumably editing in the file and the auto-completions and other features will kick in.

```json
{
   "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jsonresume/resume-schema/master/schema.json",
   "basics": { "name": "Pieter", "email": "some@email.com", ... },
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
(setq lsp-json-schemas '((json-mode . "/path/to/schema/SchemaJSONFile.json")))
```

According to the [inline documentation](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-json/#lsp-json-schemas) this variable must be a repeat alist.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/issues/3368#issuecomment-1049635155), it should be:

```lisp
(setq lsp-json-schemas
 `[(:fileMatch ["foo.json" "*.morefoo.json"] :url "http://json.schemastore.org/foo")])
```